# C++: passing 2D array as local variables but then its value in main program is changed

Tags: c++, function

In the below program, I have a function called "change" which take a 2D array as input and return an integer value. I expected that the array is local variable and its value will not be changed in main function, but unexpectedly, it is not the case. Why does this happen?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int change(int arr[2][5]) {
  int b;

  b = 1;
  arr[0][0]=0;
  return b;
}

int main(){
    int i,j, b;
    
  int arr[2][5] =
    {
        {1,8,12,20,25},
        {5,9,13,24,26}
    };

  cout << "input array \n";

  for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<5; j++) {
      cout << arr[i][j] << "  ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
  }
  cout << "\n";

  b = change(arr);

  cout << "final array \n";

  for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<5; j++) {
      cout << arr[i][j] << "  ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
  }
  cout << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

The output I got is:

```
input array 
1  8  12  20  25  
5  9  13  24  26  

final array 
0  8  12  20  25  
5  9  13  24  26
```

Comment: That's because your array decays to a pointer and the pointer to the original array is passed instead. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17569578/6205379) answer.

Comment: Unrelated: Why `#include <cstdio>`? You're not using anything from that header.

Comment: To work around this decay you can change your array from `int arr[2][5]` to `std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 2>> arr` and `#include <array>`

Comment: `change` actually takes a pointer to an array with five elements (it's equivalent to `int change(int (*arr)[5])`. Read about how arrays decay to pointers, and the slightly weird parameter type syntax, in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yeah, I simplified the code from my actual code and forgot to remove that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: oh because I do not have enough reputation to vote :( Sadly

Comment: I think I need to have at least 15 reputation or sth like that to up vote a question

Comment: @HoaTrinh You do not need any reputation to _accept_ answers. Please read the link I shared in my comment.